# Python3 PIL Pillow Ubuntu Install

Tags: ubuntu, python-imaging-library, python-3.4, installation

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 installed. I'm relatively novice when it comes to installing Python Packages in Linux.

I'm just trying to install and get access to [PIL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) image library in Python 3.4. It is my understanding that this is achieved by installing Pillow, the modern fork of PIL.

It seems in my floundering I managed to successfully get PIL working in Python 2.7, but I still cannot get it working in 3.4.

I got `pip` and `pip3`. When I enter

```
sudo pip3 install Pillow
```

I get the following error message, implying it is is installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Yet when I try to import either PIL or Pillow in Python 3.4, the module is not found.

I feel like I'm just missing something simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Pillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) is packaged as `python3-pil` in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr). You can install it system-wide with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil
```

You seem to have already installed Pillow with [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) earlier, but the default path it pip places it in is not read by the system Python.
You can add it to the search path with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Generally you are better off using `pip --user` to avoid breaking the system installations or to stick with the packaged variants of base Python modules if possible.

Comment: So I tried
    sudo apt-get install python3-pil
and it said I already had that installed.

Afterwards I tried the export line which executed on command line without any output. That still did not fix the python code. In the code I should be importing from PIL still right?

Additionally, I am a little confused by your pip --user comment. Do you mean I shouldn't do sudo pip? I'm just confused because pip apparently doesn't have a --user arg.

Comment: Ah. I finally figure it out! Thanks so much!