# PIP install PIL python2.7 ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install PIP to run an older application and have followed a number of steps the final hurdle is installing PIP.  The reason for this is the functionality I'm trying to use is showing this error:

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I followed the instruction at http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/04/19/how-to-install-pil-on-ubuntu/

And had to change the command slightly to:

sudo pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL

I'm getting some errors and not sure how to resolve these:

Can anyone share any ideas? I'm sure its just a library or something missing?

Thanks

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 582, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 625, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 543, in untar_file
    tar = tarfile.open(filename, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1678, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1727, in gzopen
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1705, in taropen
    return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1574, in __init__
    self.firstmember = self.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2335, in next
    raise ReadError(str(e))
ReadError: invalid header

Storing debug log for failure in /home/peek/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Just as it reads on the tin (c) - an archive appears to be corrupt. What does the referred `pip.log` say?

Comment: Here's the log file:

Comment: mostly unpacking info then:

Comment: the same as above (won't let me post log file - too long...

Comment: Post in into the question instead and only include interesting parts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check again, how many bits of your computer?

```
install PIL on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04
```

How about this?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/507459/pil-install-in-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg8 libjpeg62-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
$ sudo pip install Pillow
```

For Check Version on Python

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.VERSION
'1.1.7'
```

Comment: Hi, I just did an install of Pillow (actually an upgrade), still getting the following error:

Comment: Successfully installed Pillow
Cleaning up...
peek@peeklinux:~/Downloads/ndvisrc/infrapix$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jan 19 2015, 21:02:01) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
>>>

Comment: `sudo pip3 install Pillow`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210936/python3-pil-pillow-ubuntu-install

Comment: so has pillow installed under the later version rather than 2.7 as I want it to?

Comment: maybe you can update your repository to can use that module..
`$ sudo apt-get update`
`$ sudo apt-get autoremove`
`$ sudo apt-get autoclean`