# Importing pycreenshot gives error "No module named 'PIL'" on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use pyscreenshot on Ubuntu 16.04 using Python version 3.5.2

I've followed the Ubuntu install instructions on the pyscreenshot website:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python-pil
sudo pip install pyscreenshot
```

The Python code fails on:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
```

with this error message:

```
from PIL import Image
ImportError: 'No module named PIL'
```

I've seen mentioned on other StackOverflow question that I should try

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil
```

but that hasn't helped either, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pil`?

Comment: It was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210936/python3-pil-pillow-ubuntu-install

Comment: Remove the update and mark as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was installing Pillow instead of PIL:

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: Yup this works. It has been renamed in py3 as far as i can recall.